# FlutterSomePackagePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API

Tags: firebase, gradle, flutter-dependencies

This problem has given two solutions changing `minSdkVersion` to 23 and setting `multiDexEnabled` to true, on the internet but none worked for me,

when I run `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety` I get this error

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geocoder-0.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\aloisdeniel\geocoder\GeocoderPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\google_maps_flutter-2.0.9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\googlemaps\TileProviderController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\libphonenumber-2.0.2\android\src\main\java\com\codeheadlabs\libphonenumber\LibphonenumberPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       190.1s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...                 9.4s
D/FlutterLocationService(28465): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(28465): Binding to location service.
Syncing files to device SM A207F...                                272ms
```

but the package build on my phone.

the packages which are deprecated are already in their latest versions

this is pubspec.yml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  http: ^0.13.3
  percent_indicator: ^3.0.1
  js: ^0.6.3
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.20-nullsafety.5
  progress_indicators: ^1.0.0
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  dropdown_search: ^1.0.3
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
  pinput: ^1.2.0
  stripe_payment: ^1.1.4
  flutter_html: ^2.1.0
  location: ^4.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.9
  firebase_database: ^8.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.3
  dio: ^4.0.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  table_calendar: ^3.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.10
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

enabling multidex could not solve my problem.

this is android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.tingsapp.customers"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

this is `flutter doctor`

```
PS C:\Users\amu\Desktop\projects\mobile apps\tingsapp-customer\customer> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1165], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.61.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

this is `flutter --version`

```
PS C:\Users\amu\Desktop\projects\mobile apps\tingsapp-customer\customer> flutter --version
Flutter 2.2.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d79295af24 (4 months ago) • 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
Engine • revision 91c9fc8fe0
Tools • Dart 2.13.3
```

any helps please,